# How to change tab logo in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change this default logo

[image]

How to change??

Comment: That is called favicon, you can change it from admin if you go through it once. There are a lot of places on "web" where you could easily found that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Log into your Magento admin panel and navigate to System > Configuration:
Navigate to General > Design tab:
Expand HTML Head section and find Favicon option:
Click Choose file button and choose your favicon image file:
After choosing the file, click Save config button:

Comment: be sure to choose the right shop view, if you have a multi store installation